# Troubles with deploying Meteor bcrypt to server with old node v 0.10.40

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a troubles with deploying meteor (METEOR@1.1.0.3) app to server using Node.js v 0.10.40.
And I have that errors:

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
 {"node":">=6"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine path-key@2.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/root/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
npm ERR!     at /root/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
npm ERR!     at saved (/root/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-25-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/th_editor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! not ok code 0
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
 > ./bcrypt: npm install due to binary npm modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's may be problems on deploying server... Because before deploying works fine! And in the moment it's crashed...

Any other solutions on StackOverflow didn't help...

I can't update node version and app. Is there any solutions?)
Thanks.

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Hello) No... I have same version on the server... And it diesn't work.

Comment: So doesn't work means the same error is thrown or a new error came up?

Comment: same error) But I want try to deploy project without mup. Using only meteor.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in my answer? If you have exactly the same error, which contains `... wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40" ...` then you definitely did not install the latest version of `node`. Please try the steps and update (append) your question if the error output has even slightest changes. The answer I wrote is targeting pure node, no MUP involved.

Answer (score 1):

Each Meteor release is built against a very specific version of `node` in order to integrate with ease and stability.

When you build a Meteor app using `meteor build` it creates a bundle, where npm modules are configured to target these specific version when building native extensions on `npm install` on your production machine.

So in order to deploy a custom build with success you first need to check your development version of node inside Meteor via

*local*

```
meteor node -v
v8.15.1 # note: this is the version for 1.8.1
```

This version needs to be installed on your server, otherwise it will fail. Note, that you can install several versions of node on your server at the same time.

A fast and easy way to install a specific version is using `n`:

*server*

```
npm install --global n
n 8.15.1
```

which will install `node@8.15.1` ins this example.

Readings

https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n